# Google Home Account Linking (An error occurred in returning the result.)

Tags: oauth-2.0, dialogflow-es

I am trying to implement oAuth2 Linking between my WeApibApp application, and Google Home. I have implemented IdentityServer4 in order to generate my oauth2 token, that I am attempting to pass back to google thought their redirect uri, this all appears to be working correctly, but I am receiving An Error occurres in the returning from the result from the call to oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com, no other indication of what the problem can be, has anyone run into this issue, and perhaps have some idea of what the issue could be. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and the silly mistake we did was we were using "?" instead of "#". 
As per the documentation there should be a # after PROJECT_ID

```
https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/YOUR_PROJECT_ID#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=bearer&state=STATE_STRING
```

Please check if you are doing the same mistake.